# UIImagePickerController's shutter

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have bug with UIImagePickerController which source type is camera. Sometimes after controller appeared, shutter is not opens up and I can't to see a camera video signal, but photo taken is correct.
[image]

May be I doing something wrong? Code:

```
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){

            UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
            cameraUI.showsCameraControls = NO;
            cameraUI.delegate = self;

            NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
            UIView *controlsView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];

            CGRect overlayViewFrame = cameraUI.cameraOverlayView.frame;
            CGRect controlsFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, CGRectGetHeight(overlayViewFrame) - 54.0,
                                         CGRectGetWidth(overlayViewFrame), 54.0);

            controlsView.frame = controlsFrame;
            [cameraUI.cameraOverlayView addSubview:controlsView];

            [self presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];            
    }
```

Comment: are you doing something very processor intensive at the point where you show the picker?

Comment: no, I don't. Shutter just hang up at infinitive time, but all controls responds normally

Comment: One clarification! Recently I noticed, what bug reproduces after going from task bar to application:
First step - turn application to task bar
Second - turn on application from task bar
Third - make camera initialization

Comment: I fixed the bug. I forgot to release a cameraUI at end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same was happening to me after locking/unlocking the app, it looks like the shutter opens on viewDidAppear.

So, I subscribed my parent view controller to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and re-execute manually the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods of the controller containing the UIImagePickerController

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationBecomeActive)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];

.
. 
.

- (void)applicationBecomeActive {
    if (imagePicker_)
        [imagePicker_ openShutter];
}
```

And then on the controller containing the UIImagePickerController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [imagePickerController_ viewWillAppear:animated];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [imagePickerController_ viewDidAppear:animated];
    imagePickerController_.cameraFlashMode = cameraFlashMode_;
    imagePickerController_.cameraDevice = cameraDevice_;
}
- (void)openShutter {
    [imagePickerController_ viewWillAppear:YES];
    [imagePickerController_ viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

PS: If you try this, don't forget to remove the observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are presenting the `UIImagePickerController` not modally (the recommended way), then you can either call the viewDidAppear and willAppear manually, or add the UIImagePickerController as child view controller from where you are presenting .

```
[thePresentingViewCotnroller addChildViewController:imagePickerController];
```

after this you can add the view from the imagePickerController as a subview, this will make the view life cycle methods (`viewWillAppear, didAppear and disappear`) called automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding auto release when you initialize the `UIImagePickerController`:

```
UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
```