# UIImagePickerController Camera Shutter not opening

Tags: ios6, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode4.6

I have a UIImagePickerController , in source type camera.
 Some times the camera shutter doesn't open but, I can take photo.

Sometimes it works fine?

[image]

I using sub class of UIImagePickerController

```
- (id)init{

    self = [super init];
        if (self) {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){


                    [self setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

                     self.showsCameraControls =NO;
                    [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
                    self.cameraOverlayView = bottomToolBar;
                    self.cameraOverlayView = topToolBar;

                }
                else{
                    [self setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
                }
        }
    }
```

bottomToolBar and topToolBar are toolbar.

anybody can help me.

Comment: Now edited source code.

Comment: it added in init function. it is sub class of UIImagePickerController

Comment: The problem was memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. There are similar threads on SO. Unfortunately none of them worked for me and I had to resort to **re-instantiating the image picker** every time it is opened.

You should read these two threads to see if any of their solutions work for you.

[UIImagePickerController's shutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998605/uiimagepickercontrollers-shutter)

[Custom ios camera shutter not opening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411606/custom-ios-camera-shutter-not-opening)

Comment: The problem was memory issue.